# Enable basic authentication on appharbor

Tags: c#, wcf, basic-authentication, appharbor

How to enable basic authentication in app deployed on appharbor.com? I've enabled it on local IIS and everything works fine, but when making requests to WCF on apphb, all responsee hav status 400.